# Ethereum address and port on local host

Tags: ethereum

I've geth node running on my local and I need to find out http url and ethereum url to deploy dapp on Mix IDE. Can any one please help and tell where to find these two parameters ?

Comment: Welcome! The [Ethereum StackExchange](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com) would have more people able to answer the question. (I'd answer it but not sure.)

Answer (score 1):

If you are in default mode probably one of those ports:

- 8545 TCP, used by the HTTP based JSON RPC API
- 8546 TCP, used by the WebSocket based JSON RPC API

Are you connecting through JSON RPC API?

```
$ geth attach ipc:/some/custom/path
$ geth attach http://191.168.1.1:8545
$ geth attach ws://191.168.1.1:8546
```

Note that by default the geth node doesn't start the http and weboscket service and not all functionality is provided over these interfaces due to security reasons. These defaults can be overridden when the **--rpcapi** and **--wsapi** arguments when the geth node is started.